# Webpack styles applies late

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack to build my client-side code.
When I load my page with bundle linked for about half a second html renders without styles. I know that this is cuz webpack bundle inlines styles in html. But that looks ugly.
Is there a way to avoid this use-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you're waiting for the js to execute and add styles to the page. If your script tag isn't in head you could put it there. The better answer is to use the `ExtractTextPlugin` plugin to produce a css file you can load traditionally. Read about it here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html

Comment: Thank you, gunn! Thats exactly what I'm lokiing for.